# Python pywin32 error passing an optional string via a VBA click

Tags: python, vba, ms-access, pywin32

I am working with legacy access code and am using pywin32 to automate batch processing.

This python code:

```
import win32com.client as win32
access = win32.Dispatch('Access.Application')
db = access.OpenCurrentDatabase(r'C:\test\PN.mdb')
access.Forms('frm_PN_Startup').cmdScenarioExport_Click()
```

sucessfully executes this Access VBA sub

```
Public Sub cmdScenarioExport_Click()
   Export_Scenario_To_ScenarioDB
End Sub
```

I would like to pass an optional text string to fill the Access InputBox that opens in Export_Scenario_To_ScenarioDB. However, when I try

Python

```
import win32com.client as win32
access = win32.Dispatch('Access.Application')
db = access.OpenCurrentDatabase(r'C:\test\PN.mdb')
access.Forms('frm_PN_Startup').cmdScenarioExport_Click("hello")
```

Vba

```
Public Sub cmdScenarioExport_Click(Optional strTest As String = "")
    Export_Scenario_To_ScenarioDB (strTest)
End Sub
```

I get the following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<input>", line 1, in <module>
  File "C:\Users\RS\miniconda3\envs\PN_PY\lib\site-packages\win32com\client\dynamic.py", line 197, in __call__
    return self._get_good_object_(self._oleobj_.Invoke(*allArgs),self._olerepr_.defaultDispatchName,None)
pywintypes.com_error: (-2147352567, 'Exception occurred.', (0, None, None, None, 0, -2146788252), None)
```

win32api tells me that the error is

```
win32api.FormatMessage(-2147352567)
'Exception occurred.\r\n'
```

After numerous hours spinning my wheels, I'm asking for any ideas to make this work. Thank you! This is my first foray into VBA.